# R applying a function to a sub-matrix

Tags: r, matrix, apply, 4d

I have a large matrix roughly 90x100x90x200  The first 3 dimensions are spatial and the last is time.  To apply a mask to my data, I wish to multiply the first 3 dimensions by the mask of the same dimensions for all 200 time points.  Is there an _apply function that can be used to do this?  Thanks for any suggestions.

-D

Comment: maybe `sweep(Array,4,mask,"*")` ?  (Not entirely sure what you mean by "mask")

Comment: Objects of more than 2 dimensions are not called 'matrices' in R.

Comment: I'm asumming the mask is an array of 0/1 or 1/NA, but you should confirm. If so, the answer is what @Ben proposed.

Comment: @agstudy, why did you delete your answer?  Even if `sweep()` is a more precise answer, yours (with `apply`) still works ...